# Ошибка: Для носителя поддерживаются только пакеты URI исходного узла

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь воспроизвести mp4 видео в MediaElemnt WPF. 
Получаю такую ошибку:
Для носителя поддерживаются только пакеты URI исходного узла.

```
public IntroScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string characterFolder = GetCharacterFolder(GameState.Instance.Character);

        media.MediaFailed += Media_MediaFailed;

        media.Source = new Uri($"pack://application:,,,/AppData/Моя папка 1/{characterFolder}/Intro.mp4");

        media.Play();
    }
```

Гугление в рунете ничего не дало. Что означает эта ошибка? Куда копать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как бы... scheme `pack://application:,,,/` указывает на то что ресурс зашит в программу.

Comment: Файл находится в ресурсах по указанному пути. Действие при сборке "Resource"

Comment: Папка AppData в проекте тоже есть?

Comment: @LiptonDev добавил скрины

Comment: @АлександрЛи Дебажте "GameState.Instance.Character" этот участок, посмотрите какое имя у вас там, может там не то, что вы ожидаете

Comment: @LiptonDev, тоже подумал. Перенес intro в AppData и изменил строку Uri на такую: new Uri($"pack://application:,,,/AppData/Intro.mp4");
Та же ошибка.

Comment: Попробуйте действие при сборке сделать как "Содержание"

Comment: @LiptonDev, попробовал, все та же ошибка.

Comment: Попробуйте тогда просто положить в папку Debug/Release AppData со всеми видео файлами и поменяйте, соответственно, свой Uri

Comment: @LiptonDev, убрал действие при сборке и поставил копирование в выходной каталог и указал строку: new Uri($"AppData/Intro.mp4", UriKind.Relative);
Это работает. Однако, хотелось бы видео файлы держать в ресурсах приложения, а не отдельным файлом.

Comment: А для чего они вам в приложении? Чтобы .exe весил 100-N МБ? Я не думаю, что это особо удобно

Comment: @LiptonDev, это игрушка. Требований к весу не было. А вот видео - коммерческая собственность, если файлы будут так свободно валяться - заказчик взбунтуется.

Comment: При желании можно вытащить что угодно, вас не спасет даже обфускация, ну это, конечно, ваше дело, если вопрос решен, то напишите ответ от своего имени :)

Comment: Любой ресурс, да даже ваш код написанный на C# можно без труда вытянуть. Так что как-то бредово говорить о "коммерческой собственности".

Comment: @LiptonDev, ну вытащить то понятно можно, но для этого потребуются хотя бы минимальные познания. А вот если файлы будут валяться прямо в папке - то любой школьник сможет их взять.

Comment: @LiptonDev, Надо в ресурсы пихать. Если нет идей, то пойду городить велосипед с заливом ресурсов во временные файлы и чтением от туда.

Comment: @АлександрЛи, напишите свой проигрыватель, который будет читать файлы из ресурсов... Трудоемко? Читайте файлы, к тому же вам никто не мешает переименовать файлы допустим в `Intro.dat` и передавать этот файл в проигрыватель, ему без разницы какое расширение у файлов.

Comment: Из [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.mediaelement): `При распространении мультимедиа вместе с приложением файл мультимедиа нельзя использовать как ресурс проекта. Вместо этого в файле проекта необходимо выбрать тип мультимедиа Content и задать для CopyToOutputDirectory значение PreserveNewest или Always.`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, спасибо.